# Any ccTalk libraries available?

Tags: c#

I want to integrate a coin acceptor into one of our applications. This specific coin acceptor uses the [ccTalk protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CcTalk) ([specs here](http://cctalk.org)).

I've been looking for a ccTalk library which I can use from C#, but until this point I've only found [this open source project](http://code.google.com/p/libcctalk/) which seems not quite ready, and abandoned.

Any of you guys know of any ccTalk libraries out there? I can't believe this hasn't been done before. It doesn't necessarily has to be free.

Comment: hi fretje! It's been long since you posted your question, and I'm in the same position now and I looked at both the project you mentioned and the project @J.Kommer referenced, but to no luck (I can't get past the connecting to the coin acceptor). So, am wondering if you had any luck on this?

Comment: @Nikola: I ended up using a closed source library provided by the supplier of this specific coin acceptor I was using.

Comment: hmm, I'm in big trouble :/, as the supplier hasn't got/doesn't want to give us the library - which is, I know, totally unbelievable!

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at [cctalk-net](http://code.google.com/p/cctalk-net/)? It's a rewrite of [libcctalk](http://code.google.com/p/libcctalk/) and has been worked on up to August 2011 this year. It does not support everything in ccTalk but might just support enough for your needs.

Comment: was libcctalk a complete library?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to come up with a solution based on the aforementioned [cctalk-net](http://code.google.com/p/cctalk-net/) project.

I hosted my project on github: https://github.com/Hitman666/nbCcTalkCoinAcceptor so I hope it will help someone. I made a full fledged documentation for an easy start (which can't be said for cctalk-net project).

Comment: Hello Nikola, how complete is your ccTalk library? Which functionality does it provide? You do not have any implementation in C or C++, do you?

Comment: Hi MeJ, I would suggest you download the project from github and go through the  documentation. Best of luck!

Comment: @Nikola Even though note accepting is not tested, how can I accept them using your library? It is not described in your documentation

Comment: @John: With my changes - you can't. As I didn't make anything regarding the note acceptor. I only made the coin acceptor to work. However, the main project from which this has been forked has that supposedly so feel free to play with that and if you solve it push the fix - I didn't test that as for note acceptor I used a different protocol as per the requirements I had. Good luck!

Comment: @Nikola The main is cctalk-net? because there I did not find anything about note acceptor either

Comment: Yes, this is the one: https://code.google.com/p/cctalk-net/

Comment: @Nikola I am trying to work with your cctalk library and I have a question. What does the address (single byte) denote in the coinAcceptor and billAcceptor constructors. In your test project you set it as 2, but what does it stand for? how can I know what to set it to?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou: The way I figured it out, it's the number representing the coin acceptor. But, honestly, more info about it I don't have, nor did I manage to get it. I tried experimenting with different numbers but it seems this one was the only one working for me. How I came to that number, I really don't remember anymore - could it be in some docs or something. I know it's not of help, so if you find it out please share with others. I played the "sneaky programmer motto" in this one "if it works - don't touch it".

Comment: @Nikola well I want to work with a bill acceptor so I don't know what works. I'm trying different numbers and different baudrates trying to get through but nothing does :P

Comment: @JohnDemetriou: I actually never got the bill acceptor working with cctalk. I ended up using the eSSP protocol, because my bill acceptor was programmed to that and it had an example c# code with it (yay!). So, yeah, sorry but the project is indeed titled Coin acceptor ;) If you make it work, share it with the world :) Good luck!

Comment: @Nikola eSSp protocol? What is that?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou: http://www.innovative-technology.co.uk/de/support/faq/item/143-essp-encrypted-smiley-secure-protocol

Comment: @JohnDemetriou the number is defined in the ccTalk protocol specification maintained by Crane Payment Innovations.  The website listed in the docs that took me weeks to find is www.CCTalk.org but this just redirects to their main page.  you could try to contact their support for the latest copy of the protocol.  I was able to get a copy of version 4.7 mid 2016 denoted to be last updated on 16 Aug 2013.  it is a 4 part specification.

Comment: @xtreampb sorry mate. Stop caring about this 1.5 years ago when I switched jobs. And from what I hear everyone at my old company stopped caring about this as well

Comment: yep just wanted to give anyone else who might be plagued with this to have a better starting place than I did