# C# function equivalent to CCtalk protocol

Tags: c#, serial-port, protocols, cctalk

Im looking fordward to integrate a coin acceptor into one of our divices. This specific coin acceptor CF7000 uses the [ccTalk protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CcTalk)

I've been working with the default libraries provided from the supplier which I can use in C#, however i want to see if its possible Find and USE a **C# Function equivalent to the cctalk protocol** and if possible use it directly into my C# code

i have been using ILSpy to open and explore the libraries provided and found this function that opens the device so it can recieve coins and store them

in my code all i have to type is:

```
DispositivoCF7000.BeginTransaction();
```

in order for the device to call the following function inside the library

```
public override void BeginTransaction()
{
    if (this.changerState == ChangerStatus.Opened)
    {
        this.UpdateAPILogger();
        string logFileLine = CF7XXX.GetCurrentDate() + "|" + CF7XXX.GetCurrentTime() + "|C|BeginTransaction()";
        this.m_Logger.Write(logFileLine);
        this.Enable(this.creditLimit);
        this.EnableFreeVend();
        this.ClearCredit();
    }
}
```

Now what i want to do is Find the CCTalk Protocol equivalent to this library function, in order for me to interact with the device, without the need to call the function from the library, however im not so sure this is easy or possible hopefully someone here might have a little bit more experience with this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any ccTalk libraries available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721885/any-cctalk-libraries-available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do what you want you have to communicate directly to the USB/Serial port and send directly the commands you want, and then build your own library or helper functions.

1. Open serial port
2. Generate the message to be sent, calculate checksum
3. Write the message on the serial interface
4. Listen for the answer if any.

Hope I've helped.